# Using a channel of maps in go

Tags: dictionary, go, channel

I'd like to pass a map through a channel in go:

```
func main() {
    var pipe map[string]string
    pipe = make(chan map[string]string, 2)
    go connect("myhost", "100", pipe)
    out := <-pipe
...}
```

so that the func() passes response and error through the channel:

```
func connect(host string, url string, pipe chan<- map[string]string) {
    fmt.Println("Trying "+url)
    var lpipe map[string]string
    lpipe = make(map[string]string)
    lpipe["resp"], lpipe["err"] = "aaa","bbb"
    pipe <- lpipe
}
```

The compiler rejects both

```
    pipe = make(chan map[string]string, 2)
:cannot use make(chan map[string]string, 2) (type chan map[string]string) as type map[string]string in assignment
```

and

```
    pipe = make(chan map, 2)
:unexpected comma, expecting [
```

What am I doing wrong? The whole thing is for being parallelized into goroutines.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what you're doing wrong: You're trying to assign a value of type `chan map[string]string` to a variable of type `map[string]string`:

```
var pipe map[string]string
pipe = make(chan map[string]string, 2)
```

Here you're creating a variable called `pipe` of type `map[string]string`, then on the second line, you're creating a channel (of type `chan map[string]string`) and trying to assign it to that variable. That doesn't work.

You're doing the same thing in your second code example.

`map[string]string` and `chan map[string]string` are distinct types.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the admittedly trivial question.